# Dynamically created `TextBox` is not getting value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created one `TextBox`, `PasswordBox` and `Button` for `ClickEvent` dynamically. When user press student or teacher `Button`. Now Problem is that `TextBox` is not getting value when I click on it. Mean as I click on textfield curser should bling on it and get value I wrote in it. but it is not getting it. `PasswordBox` is working fine. 
Sorry for bad English. 
here is my code

```
        TextBlock name_block = new TextBlock();
        name_block.Text = "Enter your ID : ";
        name_block.Margin = new Thickness(5, 8, 0, 0);
        container.Children.Add(name_block);

        TextBox name_box = new TextBox();
        name_box.Width = 200;
        name_box.Height = 25;
        name_box.IsEnabled = true;
        name_box.Margin = new Thickness(150, 5, 1, 1);
        container.Children.Add(name_box);


        TextBlock pass_block = new TextBlock();
        pass_block.Text = "Enter your password : ";
        pass_block.Margin = new Thickness(5, 78, 0, 0);
        container.Children.Add(pass_block);

        PasswordBox pass_box = new PasswordBox();
        pass_box.Width = 200;
        pass_box.Height = 25;
        pass_box.IsEnabled = true;
        pass_box.Margin = new Thickness(150, 75, 0, 0);
        container.Children.Add(pass_box);

        Button login_btn = new Button();
        login_btn.Content = "Login";
        login_btn.Height = 25;
        login_btn.Margin = new Thickness(150, 150, 0, 0);
        container.Children.Add(login_btn);

        teacher_btn.IsEnabled = false;

        login_btn.Click += Teacher_Login_btn_Click;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Grid with out setting grid columns and rows. Seeing your code you can use canvas layout container as you are setting location for your controls.

```
        <Canvas Name="container" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" />
```

Rest of your code works if you are using canvas container.

otherwise let me know which layout container you are using.